# Adding noise to a column of data

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am working with this optdigits data set from UCI machine learning repository and want to create a new training dataset with noise. How to randomly add noise to a vector in R? say corrupt 10% of the values of the vector.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: corrupt in what way?

Comment: change 10% of the values of the vector to a random class (0 to 9).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the kind of noise you want to add.

Here's an example:

```
x <- runif(100,100,150)  # this is our original vector, which I'm just making up

corrupt <- rbinom(length(x),1,0.1)    # choose an average of 10% to corrupt at random
corrupt <- as.logical(corrupt)
noise <- rnorm(sum(corrupt),1000,200) # generate the noise to add
x[corrupt] <- x[corrupt] + noise      # about 10% of x has been corrupted
```

Here's a plot of corrupted values against the original ones:

[image: plot of corrpted against original x]

You should substitute your own vector and the kind of noise.

Edit: I've just seen your response to my question. To get a random value from 0 to 9, you use `sample` like so:

```
noise <- sample(0:9,sum(corrupt),replace=TRUE)
```

and because you're replacing rather than adding, you then do:

```
x[corrupt] <- noise
```

Giving this on the same data as before, and with the same values replaced:

[image: With replacement noise from sample function]

If you wanted to replace a precise number of values (exactly 100 of 1000 values say, rather than an average of 100), you could `sample` to choose from a set of indices indicating which values to replace.

Comment: I suggest you be very careful to work on *copies* of the data.